# React Activity OnHostPause/OnHostResume methods throw errors in Android Studio

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

OnHostPause and onHostResume are methods that I saw in the Facebook React-Native tutorial for Integration with Existing Apps section. However, when I tried to use the sample code they gave me it is throwing an error at the methods OnHostPause/OnHostResume/OnHost.... Does anyone know why it is doing this and what methods I should be calling instead?

[image]

Comment: Did you instantiate your mReactInstanceManager?

Comment: Yes I did use mReactInstanceManager

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to add
`implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler`

```
public class MyReactActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {
...
}
```